# Redirecting index.html to root + folder index.html to root folder? (multilingual)

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect

I have example.com page. I want a homepage without index.html (example.com/index.html -> example.com)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It works but what rule to create for folder /de/ (language)?

Code above in folder /de/ redirects me to example.com (example.com/de/index.html or example.com/de/index -> example.com). **Correct link: example.com/de/**

How to make a rule for /de/ folder? How to modify rule?

**Expected effect**

```
example.com/index.html example.com/index -> example.com
example.com/de/index.html example.com/de/index -> example.com/de/
```

.htaccess - example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
Options +Multiviews
```

.htaccess - example.com/de/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /de/
Options +Multiviews
```

Comment: Your rule now looks correct to me.   You could have an old redirect cached by your browser.  Have you tried clearing your browser cache before testing again?   Have you tried testing with `curl --head` on the command line?

Comment: To confirm... you _only_ have this code in the `.htaccess` file in the document root directory? You have no other `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Cache clean - not working. Question edited @MrWhite

Comment: "I want a homepage without `index.html`" - To confirm, you are already _linking_ to the canonical URLs, without `index.html`?

Comment: Yes, canonical URLs without .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically just need to remove the `/de/.htaccess` file altogether!<sup>***1**</sup> Your root `.htaccess` already performs the necessary redirects.

(<sup>***1**</sup> Or remove all the directives and keep the `ErrorDocument` directive if you need a separate language-specific 404 file. But see the note below regarding the format of the `ErrorDocument` directive.)

The `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]` directive in the `/de/.htaccess` file is redirecting the request back to the document root and losing the subdirectory. But as stated above - this is not required anyway.

You will need to clear your browser cache, as 301s are cached persistently by the browser - better to test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason.

> ```
> example.com/de/index
> ```

I would also question whether you really need to redirect `index`? This is only accessible because you've enabled `MultiViews`. Personally, I would disable `MultiViews` (which can cause additional conflicts with mod_rewrite if you're not careful) and just let requests for `/index` fail with a 404.

With `MultiViews` enabled, all your HTML files and static resources are accessible without the extension.

In other words, to ensure that `MultiViews` is disabled:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Note that `MultiViews` is disabled by *default*. (Although some shared hosts do explicitly enable it in the server config for some reason.)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
> ```

You could reduce these two directives into one if you wish:

```
RewriteRule ^(|.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 /
> ```

You should specify the full URL-path to the error document, instead of relying on mod_dir issuing a subrequest for the directory index. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

### Summary

Your root `/.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable MutliViews
Options -Multiviews

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

RewriteEngine on

# Remove www subdomain and redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove "index.html" from all URLs
RewriteRule ^(|.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, everything works now